# Check two returned values from an Array in an if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, icons

My array contains random numbers, the following method succesfully returns the two largest values of it:

```
 int[] a = {a1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a3 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1)};

public static int[] showtwolargestints(int a[]) {   // returns two largest integers of my array
int largestA = Integer.MIN_VALUE, largestB = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int value : a) {
  if(value > largestA) {
    largestB = largestA;
    largestA = value;
  } else if (value > largestB) {
    largestB = value;
  }
}
return new int[] { largestA, largestB };
```

}

What I want to do now, is after pushing a button in my GUI, I want to show up certain labels/pictures, depending on what my two largest integers are.
Since I am a beginner I do not really know a good method to compare them:
This is my code in the GUI class / JButton method:

```
public void buttonmethod() {   
try {                         
  if (Arrays.toString(myobject.showtwolargestints(myobject.a)).equals("[10, 10]")) {
    label1.setVisible(true);
    Icon i1 = new ImageIcon("pics/ten.png");
    label1.setIcon(i6);

    label2.setVisible(true);
    Icon i2 = new ImageIcon("pics/ten.png");
    label2.setIcon(i7);
  } // end of if
  else if (Arrays.toString(myobject.showtwolargestints(myobjects.a)).equals("[10, 9]")) {
     label1.setVisible(true); // and so on...
```

I do get results, however they dont seem to work properly since every few starts of my programm, after pushing my Button,
it either shows only one label, or no change at all :l

Comment: The icons are called `i1` and `i2`, but you're setting `i6` and `i7` as the icons. Typo?

Comment: 1. store the returned array in a variable to avoid computing the largest values several times. 2. Just use `if (array[0] == 10 && array[1] == 10)` to compare the elements (or better, put this in a reusable method taking the array and the two vlues to compare it to as argument). 3. Use your debugger to understand what happens. We don't know what you expect to happen, what happens instead, and what the array contains, so we can't help. But your debugger can.

Comment: It seems to me that the second half of [Andy Turner’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42316796/5772882) is really what you want to do. However, if you mean it when you say you want to check the returned array, you may do `Arrays.equals(twoLargest, new int[] { 10, 10 })` etc. Not most elegant, but I think it reflects what you want, which is always nice for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Doing stuff with the `toString` is inefficient (especially if you calculate the largest elements array and their string representation repeatedly) and clunky.

Just compare the array elements directly:

```
int[] twoLargest = myobject.showtwolargestints(myobject.a);
if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 10) {
  // ...
} else if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 9) {
  // ...
}
```

---

But it looks like you could simplify your code by putting your filenames into an array:

```
String[] filenames = {"pics/zero.png", ... "pics/ten.png"};
```

And then just saying:

```
label1.setVisible(true);
Icon i1 = new ImageIcon(filenames[twoLargest[0]]);
label1.setIcon(i1);

label2.setVisible(true);
Icon i2 = new ImageIcon(filenames[twoLargest[1]]);
label1.setIcon(i2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing them directly has worked fine for me.

Is there a clean way to add together the rest of the integers in the array? My program does not to seem to be very happy with my attempt.

What I have tried is:

```
int sum = 0;
  for( int i : maxis) {
    sum += i;
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by “comparing them directly”, please? `arr1 == arr2`? `arr1.equals(arr2)`? Neither of those work (except when `arr1` and `arr2` refer to the same array).

Comment: For your follow-up question, you should ask a new question. And again explain better.